# Android 2x2 buttons: same size when the content is different

Tags: android, button, size

I have an `Activity` with an `Image` and a 2x2 button bar (`TableLayout`). I want it to be like this:

[image]

The `TableLayout` with the buttons will fill all the space left by the image. I want all the buttons to have the same size (height and width). Right now I'm using this code:

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/myImage"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:onClick="Clicked" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:onClick="Clicked" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:onClick="Clicked" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:onClick="Clicked" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

This works if the `Buttons` have the same content, but if the first Button has 1 line of text and the last one has 2 lines then the second row's height is higher than the first one. How can I fix it?

I tried adding  android:layout_weight="1"  in all the Buttons, but it's still not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to solve it from code:

```
buttonBar = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttonBar);

button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

button1.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int height = buttonBar.getHeight();
            button1.setHeight(height/2);
            button2.setHeight(height/2);
            button3.setHeight(height/2);
            button4.setHeight(height/2);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add 
`android:layout_weight="0.5"` property in each `Button`.

Comment: Please can you check the comments on Shobhit Puri answer? He answered the same but it's not working for me.